How to obtain a reference to the configured ExecutionGraphQlService
I have a spring-graphql project configured using Spring Boot using Spring MVC to handle GraphQL queries over HTTP. I also want to execute GraphQL queries on the server side. How would I get a reference to the configured ExecutionGraphQlService?

OK. This turns out to have been fairly straightforward. I just needed to auto-wire the reference to a GraphQlSource as in:
@Autowired
private GraphQlSource source;

